# Logstash Ruby convert Hex representation in a float

Tags: ruby

I receive from and IoT the temperature information in Hex format : 
0x41d39ce6 
But I need to convert it into a float value like this : 
26.451610565185546875
Here is my ruby code from now :

```
event.set('[ln_temperature]',event.get('[ln_temperature_B_inversion]').to_s.hex)
```

With `'ln_temperature_B_inversion'` variable is `41d39ce6`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
["41d39ce6"].pack("H*").unpack("g").first
# => 26.451610565185547
```

Your hex string is big-endian standard 32-byte float. Use `Array#pack` to get a byte string from your hex, then `String#unpack` to convert it into a float.

Comment: Doesn't seems to work with
`event.set( '[ln_temperature]', event.get('[ln_temperature_B_inversion]').pack("H*").unpack("g").first )
`

Comment: Well, I have no idea what your `event.get('[ln_temperature_B_inversion]')` is, but I doubt it is an array. Note in my answer that the hex string is inside an array. So try `event.set( '[ln_temperature]', [event.get('[ln_temperature_B_inversion]')].pack("H*").unpack(‌​"g").first )`?

Comment: That's it you were right it's working thanks very much Amadan

Comment: Starting with Ruby 2.4, you can use `unpack1('g')` instead of `unpack('g').first`